# Can you get a crash log from iTunes Connect when you build on an app you downloaded?

Tags: xcode, crash, app-store-connect

Can you get an iTunes Connect crash log when you download your app from the App Store and then build on that app using Xcode?

Let's say I have a released version, and I download it from the app store to test, then later on I want to make some changes to my code.

I don't delete the downloaded app, but I just build over it from Xcode. Then I add a lot of breakpoints during the initial launch to check. Suddenly, my app crashes because it isn't able to launch in time.

Will the crash be sent to iTunes Connect?

Also, it is possible for your app to fail launching when you have a lot of break points added and you try to step into things?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run your app from Xcode, your app is no longer the same app. It is now your development app. If it crashes, nothing is sent to iTunes.

When you run your app through Xcode, the timeout is disabled. You could let it sit for a week and the OS will not kill it for taking too long to startup.

And I believe you mean "iTunes Connect" where ever you mention "iTunes".

Comment: why did i get an app failed to launch in time when i added a lot of breakpoints? is it the xcode's problem? it only happened to me once.
the thing is, when i use time profiler, my app launches in 3 seconds. how can it have a crash like that? is there another reason it might happen?